# Css transition makes my fixed header bounce in Chrome. is there anything I can do to fix it?

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome, css-transitions

The web layout I'm working on atm has a header horizontal menu that turns into a fixed position once you scroll down. That's simple.

Then I have full background images also with a fixed position (all of them same position) with `opacity:0;` and a negative `z-index`, and, when you scroll down, the images will change as it adds a class to the container with a higher `z-index` and `opacity:1;`

This html will work as an example:

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="Menu "> 
    </div>
</div>


<div class="image2 top"> 
</div>
<div class="image1"> 
</div>
<div class="content">

</div>
```

Some Css's:

```
.header {
    height:100px;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
}
.Menu {
    height:40px;
    width:100%;
    background-color: red;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
}
.MenuFixed {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
}
.content {
    height:1200px;
}
.image1, .image2 {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    z-index:-10; 
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .3s ease;
    transition: opacity .3s ease;    
}
.top {
    opacity:1;
    z-index:-9;
}

.image2 {background-color: orange;}
.image1 {background-color: yellow;}
```

and the jquery:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {            
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 60) {
        $(".Menu").addClass("MenuFixed");                
    } else {
        $(".Menu").removeClass("MenuFixed");
    }

    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 400) {
        $(".image1").addClass("top");
        $(".image2").addClass("top");
    } else {
        $(".image1").removeClass("top");
    }
});
```

You can check the result in this **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/goLe91wm/)**

The problem is that I have added a css transition to my images so when the change happens, it will make a "fade" like effect, however when you scroll up and down at the image change point, you can see how the header menu "bounces". (you can check it better if you scroll the fiddle pressing the scroll bar). if no transition the header doesn't bounce

Could anyone tell me the why is this happening? Anyway to fix it? If I can't use css transition, is there any way to make a simmilar effect modifiying the jquery? (I'm sorry I suck at javascript and jquery)

Thanks a lot in advance and excuse my poor english. Any edits would be greetly apreciated.

Edited: As the web is in the early stages I was just working with crhome and not testing on other browsers. I just noticed is a chrome problem/bug (works perfect in IE, Safary, and Firefox) . still any "fix" is apreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to mess with the z-index via Javascript at all. Just use a z-index of 0, order the images in the desired sequence and add a class to change opacity via Javascript.

Only add the class to the image which shall appear:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {      
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 400) {
        $(".image1").addClass("top");
    } else {
        $(".image1").removeClass("top");
    }
});
```

Dont't use negative z-index and don't change z-index in added class:

```
.image1, .image2 {
    z-index:0;   
}
.top {
    opacity:1;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this works but I need to change the z-index on the added class becuase container of the image needs to stay on top of ther other container images. it may have in the future some interactive elements inside

Comment: Still work in progress. You may be right though... so I'll go at first this way and if needed I will "mess" with the z-indexes in the future if I have problems with elements inside image containers. Ty very much

Comment: If you have two containers with the same z-index the one appearing later in the source will be stacked on top. You can always use that. And remember that elements with any `position:` assigned get stacked in front of the ones without. So probably you will want to add `position: relative` to `.content` and maybe you better place the image containers first in the source code (before the header).

Comment: Read more about CSS stacking here: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/09/15/the-z-index-css-property-a-comprehensive-look/ (especially the part about "natural stacking order").

Comment: Yeah mate. I know about stacking order and, ofc the image containers will be on top of the html (as in the fiddle). THe "content" works fine as designed but I thinking about future elements inside  the image container (links and such) that won't scroll up and down with the "content" (that's why they will be placed inside the image containers)... and probably if on top of those elements there are another container ( with 0 opacity) I may not be able "play" with them. Probably I didn't explain myself well before. Apreciate your time anyway. Ty

Answer (score 0):

Well, some hours later I came with a fix for this problem. I'm answering my own question in case it could help someone else in the future.

The problem/bug with chrome is the negative z-index value for the current background image. No idea why it messess chrome but as soon as I input NO negative values for the visible image it stops the bouncing.

so I added to the header a big z-index (it is suppose to be always on top):

```
.header {
    height:100px;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    z-index:100;
}
```

change the image z-index to -1 (if hidden) and 0 (if visible)

Updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/goLe91wm/10/)**

Comment: Even with the updated fiddle the problem appears for me (Chrome), although only when scrolling up and looking a little different. But I managed to make it disappear, see my upcoming answer.

Comment: Yes.I  Noticed it later. to fix this image on bottom needs 0 z-index and on top > .0: http://jsfiddle.net/goLe91wm/11/  It's a pain since now I need to add a positive z-index to all web content.

Comment: See my answer, you don't need to mess with the z-index at all.